# log a stock/share price variable to database useing php

Tags: php, json

i have an API that retrieves stock price data through a PHP script. I have tried several different ways to add the price
to my database with no luck.

please help as this is driving me crazy, I have tried logging it as a float with different syntax but still doesn't display,
please could you be kind enough to give me an example using the code below as i am completely new to PHP/mysqli and programing in general.
thanks.
please note that I use import.io to create the API and have removed the API key.

This is how the API works:

```
<?PHP  

$url = 'http://my api url.com';
$json =file_get_contents($url);  
$retVal =json_decode($json, TRUE); 
$output = "<ul>";

foreach($retVal['results'] as $results) {
    $output .="<p>".$results['price/_source']."</p>";
}

$output .="</url>";

echo $output;   // this would show the price like so: 1.139791

?> '
```

//this is the json file.

`{`
    `"offset": 0,`
    `"results":` 
`[`
    `{`
        `"price": "1.140 293"`
    `}`

```
`]`,
```

`"cookies": [ ],`
"connectorVersionGuid": "2af429a0-3fa4-4e67-b9bf-fbf453674ccb",
"connectorGuid": "87343523-d4c8-47db-b582-5408be1b679b",
"pageUrl": "http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=EUR&to=USD&amount=1",
"outputProperties":
[

```
    `{`
        `"name": "price",`
        `"type": "STRING"`
    `}`
`]`
```

`}`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Or how is the current output appearing.

Comment: Not sure what the database component of your question is. If you are getting invalid json when you `json_decode`, this will just be false. So you will not be able to iterate over `$retVal`. Please try before you declare `$output = "<ul>"` to `print_r($retVal); die();` to make sure that your json is actually present / valid

Comment: You might also want to show us some sample data of your json so we can help you out easier.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for replying, I have attached the json file as well. Also to answer some qestions, this script does work by displaying the price, so from this example it ouputs the number;  1.140 293 ,  this is now what i want to add to my database. cheers